# Converting multiple File geodatabase (.gdb) into multiple Personal geodatabase (.mdb)

Tags: python, arcpy

Individually I will Export the gdb to XML Workspace then import that into the personnel geodatabase and all Domains go over fine. But...

Let's Say I have several file geodatabase in a folder and Each of the file geodatabase has 1 feature dataset name "URS" and rest are feature classes. "URS" Feature dataset has several feature class as well.

The task for me is to convert Multiple file geodatabase into multiple Personnel geodatabase without including "URS" Feature datasets. If the Geodatabase don't have "URS" Feature dataset or any other feature classes then the python program will create an empty personnel geodatabase.

I am using pyscripter and below mentioned concept is not workin for a single geodatabase. How can I convert multiple File geodatabase (.gdb) into multiple Personal geodatabase (.mdb)?

```
# Import system modules
import arcpy

# Set environment settings
arcpy.env.workspace = "I:\python\Multiplegdb"
print arcpy.env.workspace

# Set local variables
inFeatures = r'I:\python\Multiplegdb\ABC.gdb'
print inFeatures
outLocation = r'I:\python\Multiplegdb\ABC_Output.mdb'
print outLocation

# Execute TableToGeodatabase
arcpy.FeatureClassToGeodatabase_conversion(inFeatures, outLocation)
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take our [Tour].  As it stands I think your question is too broad for our focussed Q&A format because it seems to be simply stating your problem and then asking for "input or code in python".  I recommend that you **edit** your question to say precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck because we are not a code writing service.

Comment: When you say "personnel geodatabases", do you mean personal (*.mdb) geodatabases?

Comment: Yes.....Can you please remove a hold on my question

Comment: Do you need the feature classes contained within the "URS" feature dataset to transfer to the output personal geodatabase?

Comment: hello Aaron,No I don't need URS feature dataset in the .mdb. I  wanted to export all individual .gdb's to individual .mdb's and the .mdb name will be same as .gdb.

Comment: Hello Aaron, I just saw your code. Can you please also let me know if i want to export the feature dataset like URS and its Feature classes as well to individual .mdb. Then how the changes gonna get reflected in the code? Thank you for helping me out. Its helping me to learn pythonon situation basis.

Comment: @Spathonzer The script that I provided already searches for FC's in a FDS called "URS".  This in in the block of code under `# Get the FC's in FDS and copy to .mdb`.  If you do not need that feature, just remove it.

Comment: Thank you Aaron!!...I understand the code and i really appreciate you for the same!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one approach that performs the following actions:

1. Create a new .mdb with old FGDB name, but in new workspace
2. Find all FC's in FGDB--take into account empty FDS's
3. Copy all FC's to .mdb

---

```
import arcpy, os

arcpy.env.workspace = r'C:\temp\inws'
inws = arcpy.env.workspace
outws = r'C:\temp\outws'

fgdb = arcpy.ListWorkspaces(workspace_type = "fileGDB")

counter = 1
for f in fgdb:
    # Define the output .mdb name
    name = os.path.basename(f).split(".")[0]

    # Create a new personal gdb (.mdb)
    arcpy.CreatePersonalGDB_management(outws, name)
    outgdb = os.path.join(outws, name + ".mdb")

    # Get the FC's in FDS and copy to .mdb
    arcpy.env.workspace = os.path.join(inws, f, "")
    fcs1 = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()
    for fc in fcs1:
        arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(fc, os.path.join(outgdb, fc))

    # Get stand-alone FC's and copy to .mdb
    arcpy.env.workspace = os.path.join(inws, f, "URS")
    fcs2 = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()
    # Make sure there are FC's in the FDS
    if fcs2 != None:
        for fc in fcs2:
            arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(fc, os.path.join(outgdb, fc))

    print "%s of %s workspaces converted" % (counter, len(fgdb))
    counter = counter + 1

print "Processing complete."
```